# Удаление меню с ActionBar

Tags: android, menu, bottom-navigation-view

Имеется следующий вопрос: в программе присутствует BottomNavigationView. Чтобы добавить в него кнопки, сначала создавал меню. Однако теперь это меню и само появляется на экране (на ActionBar появляются 3 точки (к сожалению, не знаю как их назвать, но на скрине выделены красным)). Они не нужны. Как их убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас где-то создается меню (разметка для которого скорее всего лежит в папке res/menu), найдите где и удалите (если нажать alt+F7 при курсоре на лэйауте - покажет где он используется)

Comment: @Jarvis_J это понятно, но это на BottomNavigationView не повлияет? Там же эта менюха как раз используется

Comment: Посмотрите, где она используется еще. Как вариант - отключите тулбар)

Comment: @Jarvis_J все настолько плохо, что это даже не ToolBar, а ActionBar. Но отключать все же не хочется. Он в другом месте используется

Comment: `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` найдите такую функцию и удалите содержимое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в этом классе где ты хочешь убрать меню, найди:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {}
```

и поставь значение **false** на кнопки которые там имеются

для примера:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_activity, menu);
    MenuItem action_btn = menu.findItem(R.id.action_btn);
    action_btn.setVisible(false);

    return true;
}
```

**menu_activity** - это меню которое привязано к классу

**action_btn** - кнопка в этом меню